# Getting error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open D:\discortbot\credentials.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting an error [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\discortbot\credentials.json']

> Error loading client secret file: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or
> directory, open 'D:\discortbot\credentials.json'] {   errno: -4058,
> code: 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'open',   path:
> 'D:\discortbot\credentials.json' }

My code is as follows and I am working on a windows machine.

```
 fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });

fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listMajors);
});
```

I am a newbie so please help me.

Comment: What is the value of `TOKEN_PATH`? Does the directory it refers to exist?

Comment: Token path is just a CONST TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json'; this file gets created onces we get authrize which is the second code. I am getting error in credentails.json case! not in token.json ! @AKX

Comment: At least, does the `D:\discortbot\credentials.json` file exists ?

Comment: @Doubidou yes it does exist in the same directory as the code!

Comment: You can try a `fs.readdir` to list all files and check what your code really see ; if your file is present, maybe it's a chmod problem ?

Comment: Well, you can't read the file if it doesn't exist, though.

Comment: @AKX well the file exists! the problem is that same code works in node js files but when I move it on discord js it gives me errors.

Comment: Well, just to check... your directory is indeed `discortbot` and not `discordbot`?

Comment: @AKX I wrote it as discortbot everywhere. Even the directory is named in this way. It is typo but that can't be the reason for this error because the code work fine in node.js files but  won't work in discord bot!